# Ember Data adaptor does not fetch records from Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data, store

In my application I want to fetch all the records from User. JSON data is coming properly serialized from Rails and I have an adaptor on the Ember side.

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend({});
```

Also, I do have a route for my User model

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('user');
  }
});
```

Model User is set both on the Rails and Ember sides, and it's table is populated with several records in the database, but for some reason I am getting no data at all.

What step am I missing ?

Running:

```
Ember v1.12.0
Ember Data v1.0.0-beta.18
```

Comment: Please include the json data.

Comment: Show code responsible for user model declaration.

Comment: Updating to Ember v1.13.2 and ember-data v1.13.3 solved the problem ! Thanks